# Как с помощью numpy случайным образом выбрать 1 значение в каждом столбце двумерного массива?

Tags: python, numpy

Как с помощью ***numpy*** случайным образом выбрать 1 значение в каждом столбце двумерного массива?

**Дано:**

```
array = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6], 
    [7, 8, 9]
        ]
```

**Вывод** должен быть, к примеру, таким: **1, 8, 6**

Comment: Çℏėτᶄắɤẵ Çℏėτɤᶉᶄắ, годятся любые решения этой задачи. Я подумал, что на чистом python это будет сложнее

Comment: Наоборот, на чистом питоне это легче будет ))  Собираете из каждого столбца массив, да делаете `random.choice` из него. В `numpy` я сообразил, как индексы тоже рандомом получить сразу для всех столбцов, а вот как по ним взять элементы из соответствующих столбцов чтобы без цикла - не соображу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 for i in range(len(a[0])):
     print(a[random.randrange(len(a))][i])
```

Answer (score 3):

С NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 30],
    [4, 5, 6, 60],
    [7, 8, 9, 90]
])

n, m = a.shape
b = a[np.random.randint(n, size=m), range(m)]
print(b)
```

Без NumPy:

```
import random

a = [
    [1, 2, 3, 30],
    [4, 5, 6, 60],
    [7, 8, 9, 90]
]
# b = [*map(random.choice, zip(*a))]
# b = list(map(random.choice, zip(*a)))
b = [random.choice(c) for c in zip(*a)]
print(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
])

n, m = arr.shape
print(arr[np.arange(n), np.random.randint(m, size=n)])
```

`np.arange(n)` - по очереди взять каждый столбец
`np.random.randint(m, size=n)`  - `n` случайных числе от `0` до `m`

Как сказали в комментариях, у меня ошибка с строках/столбцах.

Правильный вариант:

```
arr[np.random.randint(n, size=m), np.arange(m)]
```

Comment: О, точно. Думал я насчёт `arange`, но не додумал )

Answer (score 1):

Решение для 2d массивов любой формы. Применяем к столбцам функцию `np.random.choice`.

```
array = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [4, 5, 6, 18],
    [7, 8, 9, 8]
])
print(np.apply_along_axis(np.random.choice, 0, array))
```

```
[1 2 6 4]
```

Решение для квадратных массивов. Перемешиваем строки и забираем элементы главной диагонали.

```
array = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
])
np.random.default_rng().shuffle(array)
print(np.diagonal(array))
```

```
[1 8 6]
```